# What hook to use after updating post?

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have a custom field **X** that saves it's value naturally upon submitting or updating post. User enters the value of this field.

What I want to do, is after the post is updated, I want to update another custom post meta field called **Y** automatically with the value of **X**. So the **Y** field should be updated without the user knowing it (in the back end), what is the correct hook and function that I need to use?

Comment: i think you can use save_post hook

Answer (score 0):

Hello Here you can use save_post hook which is call wether the post is created or updated.

```
function my_custom_field_save( $post_id ) {

// do your stuff here....

}
add_action('save_post', 'my_custom_field_save');
```

[More About save_post hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)

i hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can used the [save_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) action hook to update meta after the  triggered whenever a post or page is created or updated

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_custom_value', 10, 3 );
function update_custom_value( $post_id,$post, $update  ) {
  if ( 'post'== $post->post_type ) {
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['x'] ) ) {
           $x= $_REQUEST['x'];
          update_post_meta($post_id,'Y', $x);   
     }
  }
}
```

> //Edit For update Y only one time when post is create

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_custom_value', 10, 3 );
    function update_custom_value( $post_id,$post, $update  ) {
      if ( 'post'== $post->post_type ) {
        if ( isset( $_REQUEST['x'] ) ) {
               $x= $_REQUEST['x'];
               if(get_post_meta($post_id,'Y',true)=='')
               {    
                  update_post_meta($post_id,'Y', $x);   
               }
         }
      }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is when I change the value of X field while editing post, I have to click Update twice in order for the Y field to get updated. I need to updated it when the Update is clicked the first time.

Comment: You can update value of Y only 1 time when post is create, am i right ?

Comment: I need to update the value of Y whenever I create or edit the post. Field X is a dropdown list, so if I change that value and update the post, I want the Y to change as well. I just want the both value to be the same at any give time after creating or editing the post.

Comment: @JanisOzolins check my code above the exit  it's working as your last comment

Comment: But the second snippet is to update only if the Y is empty. But the hook save_post is obviously the problem because the function is performed before the field gets updated, which is the reason why I need to press Update twice for it to work. The new value of X is being updated AFTER this function is called which is why it doesn't work now..